# Multiple commands per HTTP request in CQRS implementation

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, cqrs

This question could be asking too much integration details but I am hoping it's to the point.

In my simple CQRS application, I have an HTTP PUT request looks like below which is supposed to update details of a product:

```
PUT http://localhost/products/088c1cb1-7e74-40b1-9900-4b9722f1dd85/details HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost

{
    description: "foo bar",
    warningDescription: "foo bar",
    dangerDescription: "foo bar",
}
```

When I get this request, I want to generate three commands instead of updating this straight away:

- `UpdateProductDescription`
- `UpdateProductWarningDescription`
- `UpdateProductDangerDescription`

Is this actually the appropirate behaviour you would expect in terms of CQRS or would you rather have `UpdateProductDetails` command?

Comment: The name of the commands suggest they are events, no?

Comment: @Aliostad :) thx, changed them now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this depends on how you position "Product" and its' "Description" in your domain or context. If updating just the descriptions have a business impact on your context, I would have *UpdateProductDescription* command and process that command.

But if updating the description is like updating the other properties of a product, *UpdateProductDetail* command is fine.

Comment: I agree, keep the code in the context of the problem domain. Don't make it more granular unless there is a solid business reason to do so.

Comment: yes, makes sense to tailor this based on the domain needs but I am mostly after whether firing multiple commands per HTTP operation is a no-no.

Comment: Not necessarily, commands can be more generic than resulted domain events. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Should you raise multiple commands per http request? Probably you shouldn't. What if some commands succeed but others do not? Do you process multiple commands in one unit of work? Even if you do, is it right usage of commanding? I doubt it. Are you willing to implement roll back logic in your http handlers?

Beware, In CQRS, a command can result in multiple events in the target aggreagate root **"all or none"** fashion because events can't fail. But commands can.

So *"one generic command that results in multiple specific events"* is a better choice then trying to *"combine multiple specific commands in one call"*.

Your aggregate root should decide how that generic command will be expressed in specific events.

So your logic would be like this :

```
UpdateGenericProductDescription -> (CommandHandler) -> AggregateRoot -> [ProductDescriptionUpdated, ProductWarningDescriptionUpdated, ProductDangerDescriptionUpdated]
```

See, even your business requires that much granularity, your command can stil stay generic unless required otherwise.